# Buttons stay on screen using Visual Studio / toolbox on Mac High Sierra

Tags: macos, visual-studio, android-layout

I am using Visual Studio on a Mac.
When I add buttons via the toolbox option, the buttons stay on screen. Not only in VS but also in all other programs.

Like this:
[printscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qUEFP.png)

Anyone a solution?

Answer (score 0):

According to this:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/117407/ios-designer-issues-with-toolbox-elements.html

There is a fix in the beta. I updated to the beta by going to Visual Studio Community>Check for Updates... Set the update channel to Beta not Stable. I downloaded and installed the Visual Studio for Mac update and it fixed the issue. No more floating labels.